# Does 'global' make a variable global just within class or throughout the whole script?

Tags: python, variables, global-variables

Given the following in the same script:

```
class ClassA:
    def GetExpBidBrice():
        global x
        x ='abc'

    def GetExpAskPrice():
        y = x + 'zyz'

class ClassB:
    def GetExpBidBrice():
        x = 123

    def GetExpAskPrice():
        y = x + 'zyz'
```

Does the `global` in `ClassA.GetExpBidPrice()` make `x` global just to the other method in `ClassA`? Or does it make it global right across the board i.e. in `ClassB` or any other class that uses a variable called `x`?

Comment: Fix your code, please it is hardly readable.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) It's not a hard thing to try out and get an answer for, or to find in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable is made global in the current code block only. From the [`global` statement documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-global_stmt):

> The `global` statement is a declaration which holds for the entire current code block. It means that the listed identifiers are to be interpreted as globals. It would be impossible to assign to a global variable without global, although free variables may refer to globals without being declared global.

The variable `x` in other methods is unaffected. It'll only be a global in the `ClassA.GetExpBidBrice()` method.

If you wanted it to be a global in the other methods as well (`ClassA.GetExpAskPrice()`, `ClassB.GetExpBidBrice()` and `ClassB.GetExpAskPrice()`) then you'd need to declare `x` a global in each method separately.

Answer (score 0):

The use of the `global` keyword in a given function marks any use of the variable *within that function's scope* as referring to a module-level global variable with that name.

In your example, having a method with **just** a `global` declaration has no effect on the use of the same name in other methods.

Answer (score 0):

global keyword used inside function will be effective with in that function block.
global will help you to make changes/update the global variable from within the function.

Answer (score 0):

I say "throughout the whole script".
That means in the namespace where no identation is, right after >>>

```
>>> def g():
    def f():
        global x
        print x
    return f

>>> f = g()
>>> f.func_globals is g.func_globals
True
>>> f.func_globals is globals()
True
>>> x = 3
>>> f()
3
```

This second example tells you: it is always the module/script namespace

```
>>> x = 3
>>> def g():
    x = 0
    def f():
        global x
        print x
        x += 1
    return f

>>> f = g()
>>> f() # would be 0 if x of g was used.
3
>>> f()
4
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

Methods that do *assignments* will create local variables unless they are declared with the `global` keyword in the same method.

Methods that only read the variable will attempt to read a global by that name.  For example:

```
class ClassA:
    def GetExpBidBrice(self):
        global x
        x ='abc'

class ClassB:
    def GetExpAskPrice(self):
        print(x)

a = ClassA()
b = ClassB()

a.GetExpBidBrice()
b.GetExpAskPrice()
```

Will display `abc`.

BUT:  if you omit the first method call, and just do:

```
b = ClassB()
b.GetExpAskPrice()
```

you get:

```
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
```

Now, if we change to:

```
def GetExpAskPrice(self):
    x = 'xyz'
    print(x)
```

this assignment is to a local variable called 'x', it will not affect the global.